# get value from table where date difference is more then certain value

Tags: sql, oracle, datediff

I have a table `EMPLOYEE_STATUS`, with column 
`SUBMIT_DATE` values as `11-05-18 11:27:34.086000000 AM` 
and `UPDATED_ON` values as `11-06-18 12:55:22.064000000 PM` 
which is basically current date.

I need a sql query for oracle database to find those rows where difference in days between submited date and updated on or current date is 30 days or more.
I tried `DATEDIFF` function but couldnt able to make it work.

I have tried the following (which does not work):

```
select * from EMPLOYEE_STATUS e 
where DATEDIFF(month, '12-06-18 03:34:09.448000000 PM', e.SUBMIT_DATE) >=1
```

Comment: Could you include the code you tried (which did not work)?

Comment: select * from EMPLOYEE_STATUS e where DATEDIFF(month, '12-06-18 03:34:09.448000000 PM', e.SUBMIT_DATE) >=1;

its not working.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM employee_status WHERE submit_date >= TIMESTAMP '2012-06-18 15:34:09.448' + INTERVAL '30' DAY`

Answer (score -1):

The function `DATEDIFF()` is not included in Oracle SQL server (as mentioned in this post). Instead you simply subtract the dates from each other, like this:

```
SELECT (11-06-18 12:55:22.064000000 PM) - (11-05-18 11:27:34.086000000 AM);
```

Which returns the difference in days. So you have to compensate for that (in your example, you are looking for a difference of a month, which could be anything between 28 and 31 days).

For those using **MySQL** or **SQL Server**, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, '2018-05-11 11:27:34', '2018-06-11 12:55:22') AS DateDiff;
```

Comment: i tried above and output is 

ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 80

Comment: `DATEDIFF` is not an Oracle function

Comment: @shrikant.sharma thank you for pointing that out. I am used to working in SQL Server. I have edited my answer.

Comment: ok , but it didnt work , and how to add colum name rather then having hard coded date.

Comment: @shrikant.sharma you just replace one of the values (the first one in your case) with the column name.

Comment: ok this works for me
select * from EMPLOYEE_STATUS where  trunc(bo.SUBMIT_DATE)<trunc(sysdate-30)